# Jquery to detect identical class and text for tab navi

Tags: jquery, class, text, click

Does anyone have experience detecting identical text(); and class?

here is my current code to

```
    $("ul.nav li").click(function() {

    $('ul.slideMove li').fadeOut('slow');

    var sharedata = $(this).text();
    $('ul.slideMove li[class = "'+sharedata+'" ]').fadeIn('slow');

});
```

the final goal will be to have tabbed navigation. When the text in ul.nav li is the same as a class within the the dynamic container, fadeIn().  On initial load, only one container will be visible then hide and show another container after you click the next li

If anyone can point me in the right direction i would really apprecieate it.

Currently, it hides all the containers after i click any li. Im not clear on how I can detect if the class equals the text var.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The `li[class = "'+sharedata+'"]` seems a little funky to me.  If you were checking the class of the li element, wouldn't you want to use `$('ul.slideMove li.'+sharedata).fadeIn('slow');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul.slideMove li[class = "'+sharedata+'" ]').fadeIn('slow');
```

should be

```
$('ul.slideMove li.'+sharedata).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try in the morning and accept the answer.

Comment: I seem to be having some issues in IE 7. It doesn't seem to be detecting the text(); var. are there any known issues iwth text(); in IE7 i have done similar jquery in IE7 before but for some reason it's not working.