# Jquery text() compare to title in IE7

Tags: jquery, text, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

In response to my last question here:

[Jquery to detect identical class and text for tab navi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169724/jquery-to-detect-identical-class-and-text-for-tab-navi)

I have a got it succesfully working in all browsers except IE 7. IE 8,9 FF 5,6 Safari and Chrome all can implement my code correctly except ie7.

Anyone suggestions?

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/3FrDY/

Comment: My suggestion is: Ignore IE7 and move forward.

Comment: @Tuga... "ignore IE7" ... kidding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tFvpy/)

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $(".slideMove .slide").fadeOut("slow");
    $('.slideMove .slide:eq('+i+')').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I think you are complicating something that can be very simple.

If you have (for example) three navigations:

**li

li

li**

and the three tabs:

**tab

tab

tab**

The easiest way is to grab the `index` number of the 'action button li' that will trigger the 'tab' with SAME *index* using the jQuery's `:eq()` selector.

- Doing so - you prevent code brakes due to (always possible) editor typo.

---

**jQuery API Docs:

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)**

Comment: Forgot to mention. Now you can also remove unneeded elements classes and names.

Comment: Yes i have it working. Now tho, my problem is that index(); is starting from the very top of the list.  I have added 'all' to my ul li which i believe is throwing the script off. http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/3FrDY/2/

Comment: Uh ... I can see the problem. You did not followed the links to the jQuery API to learn more about **:eq()** and **.index()** . The problem is quite simple. I'll answer you to that issue on the page you asked the new question.!

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208092/tabbed-navigation-jquery-and-css-issues/7211036#7211036