# Tabbed navigation. Jquery and CSS issues

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, navigation, indexing

Issues with a script earlier discussed.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169724/jquery-to-detect-identical-class-and-text-for-tab-navi)

Basically my html is not behaving the way i want it to.

Clicking:
All - Display all containers

```
<div class="slide">
```

Action Adventure - Display

```
<div class="slide" title="Action Adventure">
```

Drama - Display

```
<div class="slide" title="Drama">
```

And so on...

**FIXED**
*On initial load, load all containers only currently works on first load. After I click anather genre, then go back to 'All' it seems to behave strangly only displaying every other*

[New Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/3FrDY/2/)

*This issue remains*
Then, i noticed that after initial load, clicking down the list, it is displaying the next container down instead of the one with identical title and text.  I think it has to do with the index(); but im not entirely sure. I need to get this dang thing working right.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/3FrDY/1/)

Thanks guys!

ps, there is other jquery to hide the the nth-child. just ignore it.

Thanks for all the help!

One last thing I need assistance with is hide all the first-child ul's when all are visible.  Except the very first one under Action-adventure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/P3z6x/2/)

[demo with comments](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/P3z6x/3/)

Here we are using the `.index()` number of a clicked `li` - to open a TAB whose `:eq()` equals this `.index()`.

Look at this tables:
[Before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183480/jquery-text-compare-to-title-in-ie7/7183644#7183644) you had this:

```
li index        --->    .slide index
_____________________________________

Action  | 0     --->     Action | 0 
Comedy  | 1     --->     Comedy | 1
Drama   | 2     --->     Drama  | 2
Docume. | 3     --->     Docume.| 3
```

And each `li` was opening nicely his respective tab `.slide`.

But than you decided to add an element `.all` that will open ALL your tabs,
But now you have this:

```
li index        --->     .slide index
_____________________________________
All     | 0  (OPEN ALL)
Action  | 1     --->     Action | 0 
Comedy  | 2     --->     Comedy | 1
Drama   | 3     --->     Drama  | 2
Docume. | 4     --->     Docume.| 3
```

As you can see `.all` has not his specific 'brother' tab to open. It just has to OPEN ALL TABS!
But, adding this 'extra' `li` element you have 'moved' the index numbers of the other `li` elemnts by 1 up.
Now clicking the `li` **Drama** , having now the index **3** it will open the TAB that has the same index. But that's the TAB containing **Documentary** movies! as it still has the index number **3**!

To fix that new issue you have to search for a tab that has THIS index number but -1.
( **Drama** index(3)-1    =    open **Drama tab** index(2) )

```
$('ul.nav li').click(function() {

    var i = $(this).index()-1;  
    $('.slide:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(400);

});
```

Having that in mind you just have to `.fadeOut()` all previously opened tabs using the jQuery `:visible` selector. Ex:

```
$('.slide:visible').fadeOut(400);
```

That will prevent interfering your script with all other `.slide`.

And here is your script:

```
$('.slide').css({position:'relative',display:'block'});

$('ul.nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('btnSelect').siblings().removeClass('btnSelect');

    if( $(this).hasClass('all') ){
        $('.slide:visible').fadeOut(400,function(){
            $('.slide').fadeIn(400);
            $('.grid ul li:nth-child(1)').show();
        });
        return;
    }

    var i = $(this).index()-1;    
    $('.slide:visible').fadeOut(400,function(){
        $('.slide:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(400);
        $('.grid ul li:nth-child(1)').hide();
    });
});
```

You can use also: `$('.slide').eq(i).fadeIn(400);` looks prettier! :)

Comment: roXon, I need to hide the first ul of each new genre when all are displayed. I believe i can chain this event under the under the first if statement but im not completely sure.

Comment: Basically i only need one grid title

Comment: I have updated my Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/5wXpE/2/

Currently, it hides all first column titles after i click. I need it to hide all culumn titles upon load except for the very first one. Similar to the index()-1 . hide all first-child ul's exepept for the very first one.

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/5wXpE/3/   ( P.S. are you shure you readed the jQuery API for `:eq()` selectors, `.index()` ? Cause now you have to learn also [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: let me know if it's ok now with the added changes.

Comment: Yea it is working great. I have been asked to add alphabetical sorting when all are viewed. Currently, the list is sorted by genre regardless if all are viewed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: May you create a new question? Here is getting messy. Thanks! :)

Comment: My new question regarding sorting ability
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236020/sort-many-uls-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't completely answer your question, but be sure to stop queued animations before you do something like fade out:

```
$(".slideMove .slide").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow");
```

otherwise, clicking on a button a couple of times will cause the animation to run over and over

Comment: Thanks Christian. The containers no longer blink twice after i click on a genre!