# Jquery tabbed navigation with custom scroll bar

Tags: jquery, sorting, alphabetical-sort

Please see new/updated question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423874/jquery-navigation-and-jscrollpane-work-at-first-but-not-after-click

Now trying to add a [custom scroll bar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller).
Please see demo:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/LjVJt/1/)

As of now, i cannot get it to appear at all. My local source includes: jquery.ui, jquery, jquery.easing.1.3.js, jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css, jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js, jquery.mousewheel.min.js.

I believe it has to do with:

```
$('.grid').fadeOut(0);
```

I simply need to include this line somewhere in the jquery after each new menu item is clicked:

```
$("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",300,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","yes","yes",15);
```

Also, getting the following error in chrome browser:

247Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
$.fn.mCustomScrollbar.btnsScrollTimerjquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:247
jQuery.event.handlejquery-latest.js:3001
b

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the plugin? It looks like it solves the problem you described...

Comment: Currently trying it. So far, I can't figure out how to sort by the first-child only. Since my grid consists of many ul li, within many div's it simply sorts all li's regardless of which one. I tried first-child but to no avail.

Comment: Currently on another project so coming back to this tomorrow

Comment: You realise that this is one of those occasions where using a table would be make sense, semantically..?

Comment: Yes that thought came to mind. The reason being, I am not completely sure if tinySort will include all ul li child elements.  Anyways, I don't have access to the structure as much I would like so this is all I got :( . thanks

Comment: I'm working on IT! I've done it, just to fix minor issues! :) :) and a question: You want to have a button 'sort alphabetically', or you want when '.all' is clicked to immediately sort titles? (cause the second is MUCH simpler to achieve!)

Comment: Look at this! http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/WDbUJ/ Fully functional!

Answer (score 3):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jgbEx/1)

Well, with the simplified markup it's very easy (I can't say it enough that using the `array.sort()` method with jquery selector return sets is the easiest way to rearrange tabular data on a website).  Here we simply take the list of `<ul>`s and sort them with a custom sort function based on their first `<li>`.

```
var nodeList = $(".grid ul").sort(function(a,b){
    return ($(a).find("li:first").text() > $(b).find("li:first").text());
});

$(".grid ul, .grid:gt(0)").remove();

$(".grid").append(nodeList);
```

couldn't be easier :)

Comment: @roXon no problem :) hope it helps someone.  And thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: YOu can use the `:gt()` selector here : `$(".grid ul, .grid:gt(0)").remove();` !

Comment: Sorting doesn't quite work. http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/g8CRL/57/ Joseph I am now trying out your method but clone is duplicating all ul's after its appended

Answer (score 2):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/3qkPc/)

**EDIT:**
FULLY FUNCTIONAL DEMO:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/WDbUJ/)

Huuuh :) done!
Searching all around the web on how to sort UL in alphabetical order. But with NO results.

How it works:

- Cloned all existent movies into the FIRST `.slide` (Now you don't have to use any more `index -1` magic like before to get the correct `.slide` after pressing the action link)
- created a function 'sorty' :)
- grabbed all the `li` movie names into a jQuery `.data()` for each parent element `ul`
- Now the grids `ul` are holding the movie name.
- Sorted alphabetically all `ul` in the first `.slide`
- IT WORKS!

You can see that I moved some code of yours from the jQuery to the CSS (marked with // added!)
, than I removed the `if` check for the 'all' link. 

Added into the HTML a proper `.slide` that holds the 'info'
 

 jQuery will now populate this slide with the cloned elements!

And I used the jQuery selector `:gt()` to get *all the next elements but the one defined*
( That means Ex: if we use `$('.element:gt(0)').css({color:'red'});` all the elements greated than index '0' will have a red text. Just the first element will have the default color. )

---

If you have questions please ... just ask!

Now in a couple of lines it looks like:

```
$('.grid:gt(0)').find('ul:eq(0)').fadeOut(0);    // hide titles (not from the first .grid (:eq(0)))   
$('.grid:gt(0) ul:visible:not(:eq(0))').clone().appendTo( $('.grid:eq(0)') ); // after we hided all the titles - clone all UL elements to our first .slide

$('.slide:gt(0)').hide();

function sorty() {    // sort UL elements by holding data (the data will be the movie name! )
    $('.grid:eq(0) ul:gt(0)').each(function() {
        var txt1 = $(this).children('li:eq(0)').text();
        $(this).data('name', txt1);
    });
    var items = $('.grid:eq(0) ul');
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
        var charA = $(a).data('name');
        var charB = $(b).data('name');
        if (charA < charB) return -1;
        if (charA > charB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    var grid = $('.grid:eq(0)');
    $(grid).append(items);
    $('.grid:gt(0)').find('ul:eq(0)').show(); // redo visibility for infos.
}
sorty(); // run sorty!

$('ul.nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('btnSelect').siblings().removeClass('btnSelect');
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.slide:visible').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $('.slide:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```